# InterRunnableVariable Data Type

Tags: development-environment, autosar

Autosar is using c code to implementation. In C language, I can define my own data structure with `typedef struct`. If I want to use InterRunnableVariable in AUTOSAR, is it possible to define InterRunnableVariable data type with my own C data structure in design level? (Let say, I use SystemDesk from dspace for designing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Please check the Software Component Template (http://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/files/releases/4-2/methodology-and-templates/templates/standard/AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate.pdf) to see how ImplementationDataTypes of category STRUCTURE can be modeled (some examples are given there too).

Comment: Thank you @ZzetT, and yes I already read that part, The thing that make me confuse is there is a tools vendor who doesn't implement that feature yet. How I am suppose to do if my tool doesn't support that feature? Can I implementing by myself?

Comment: Are you talking about a tool vendor for the authoring tool or for the code generation? In the first case, you can model it yourself in a simple XML editor, in the second case I would change the Rte if it can't even handle simple structure types